# Dell XPS 15 9560, 9570 UHD 4K IPS touch screen differences

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, laptop-repair, dell-xps

While cleaning the screen of a preowned 9570 I received today I noticed an interesting artifact in the reflection of my light source and I'm not sure what to make of it, or it's implications to display quality?

Now that I've fined tuned the display settings for the 9560 I am perfectly happy with how it looks (sharp, crystal clarity with great contrast and lush, vibrant colors - excellent for web browsing and coding, and games too if not for the motion blur, but no matter since it isn't billed as such).

I'm going to be doing a side-by-side comparison after this post to see how they measure up (need to swap some hard drives first so wanted to get this post out quick). **I've read that the 9570 display uses less power so am not sure if any image quality was sacrificed.** **If it is an inferior panel, would it be possible and/or feasible to swap internals (figured would be easier than swapping screens and/or panels)?** Plus, the chassis on the 9560 feels sturdier and heavier - more durable and "right" - and I prefer it's shade of silver to the 9570's.

[image: 9560]
[image: 9570]

Comment: I think that whatever is causing the "X" pattern is related to a wider viewing angle.

Comment: What makes you think it's the display itself & not just different protective layers or the screen's top coat? Aside from that, there is no question here, just an observation.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, actually, it most likely is an anti-reflective layer or something. A film pattern can be seen up close at the right angle (you beat me to the punch). However, I was more concerned with getting a downgraded display since there were changes made to it for the 9570 model to consume less power and so I wasn't sure if image quality was sacrificed. Fortunately, they seem almost indistinguishable.